# How to use GPIO on STM32 (F103VET6) as a kind of of output battery?

Tags: led, stm32, embedded, gpio, led-matrix

After I learnt how to blink LEDs on the board, I came up with the idea of making a LED matrix.
The schematic is like this:

[image: SCHEMATIC]

[image]

But I could not figure out how to light it!
Every LED can be lighted under 2.3 V to 3.4 V with 13~33 mA, and STM32F103VET6 can output 3.3 with 25 mA. Therefore, I connected the pins of PORTD from No.0 to No.9 with PD0 to PD9 in the picture, using them as a kind of positive electode, and connected the pins of PORTE of No.0, No.1, No.7, No.8 and No.9, using them as a kind of negative electrode. And lines of code are shown in the following:

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"                  // Device header
#include "HAL_GPIO.h"

int main(){

GPIO_TYPE D2; //D2--PB13
D2.port = PORTB;
D2.pin = 13;
D2.mode = OUTPUT_MODE;
D2.mode_type = OUTPUT_GEN_PURPOSE;
D2.speed = SPEED_50MHZ;

gpio_init(D2);

GPIO_TYPE D3; //D3--PB14
D3.port = PORTB;
D3.pin = 14;
D3.mode = OUTPUT_MODE;
D3.mode_type = OUTPUT_GEN_PURPOSE;
D3.speed = SPEED_50MHZ;

gpio_init(D3);

//LED MATRIX Lmxn, m=1~A,n=1~5
//+: 
//PD0, PD1, PD2, PD3, PD4, PD5, PD6, PD7
GPIO_TYPE PD0;
PD0.port = PORTD;
PD0.pin = 0;
PD0.mode = OUTPUT_MODE;
PD0.mode_type = OUTPUT_OD;
PD0.speed = SPEED_2MHZ;
    
gpio_init(PD0);
    
GPIO_TYPE PD1;
PD1.port = PORTD;
PD1.pin = 1;
PD1.mode = OUTPUT_MODE;
PD1.mode_type = OUTPUT_OD;
PD1.speed = SPEED_2MHZ;
    
gpio_init(PD1);

GPIO_TYPE PD2;
PD2.port = PORTD;
PD2.pin = 2;
PD2.mode = OUTPUT_MODE;
PD2.mode_type = OUTPUT_OD;
PD2.speed = SPEED_2MHZ;
    
gpio_init(PD2);

GPIO_TYPE PD3;
PD3.port = PORTD;
PD3.pin = 3;
PD3.mode = OUTPUT_MODE;
PD3.mode_type = OUTPUT_OD;
PD3.speed = SPEED_2MHZ;
    
gpio_init(PD3);

GPIO_TYPE PD4;
PD4.port = PORTD;
PD4.pin = 4;
PD4.mode = OUTPUT_MODE;
PD4.mode_type = OUTPUT_OD;
PD4.speed = SPEED_2MHZ;
    
gpio_init(PD4);

GPIO_TYPE PD5;
PD5.port = PORTD;
PD5.pin = 5;
PD5.mode = OUTPUT_MODE;
PD5.mode_type = OUTPUT_OD;
PD5.speed = SPEED_2MHZ;
    
gpio_init(PD5);

GPIO_TYPE PD6;
PD6.port = PORTD;
PD6.pin = 6;
PD6.mode = OUTPUT_MODE;
PD6.mode_type = OUTPUT_OD;
PD6.speed = SPEED_2MHZ;
    
gpio_init(PD6);

GPIO_TYPE PD7;
PD7.port = PORTD;
PD7.pin = 7;
PD7.mode = OUTPUT_MODE;
PD7.mode_type = OUTPUT_OD;
PD7.speed = SPEED_2MHZ;
    
gpio_init(PD7);

//PD8, PD9
GPIO_TYPE PD8;
PD8.port = PORTD;
PD8.pin = 8;
PD8.mode = OUTPUT_MODE;
PD8.mode_type = OUTPUT_OD;
PD8.speed = SPEED_2MHZ;
    
gpio_init(PD8);

GPIO_TYPE PD9;
PD9.port = PORTD;
PD9.pin = 5;
PD9.mode = OUTPUT_MODE;
PD9.mode_type = OUTPUT_OD;
PD9.speed = SPEED_2MHZ;
    
gpio_init(PD9);

//-:        
//PE0, PE1, PE7
GPIO_TYPE PE0;
PE0.port = PORTE;
PE0.pin = 0;
PE0.mode = OUTPUT_MODE;
PE0.mode_type = OUTPUT_GEN_PURPOSE;
PE0.speed = SPEED_2MHZ;

gpio_init(PE0);

GPIO_TYPE PE1;
PE1.port = PORTE;
PE1.pin = 1;
PE1.mode = OUTPUT_MODE;
PE1.mode_type = OUTPUT_GEN_PURPOSE;
PE1.speed = SPEED_2MHZ;

gpio_init(PE1);

GPIO_TYPE PE7;
PE7.port = PORTE;
PE7.pin = 7;
PE7.mode = OUTPUT_MODE;
PE7.mode_type = OUTPUT_GEN_PURPOSE;
PE7.speed = SPEED_2MHZ;

gpio_init(PE7);

//PE8, PE9
GPIO_TYPE PE8;
PE8.port = PORTE;
PE8.pin = 8;
PE8.mode = OUTPUT_MODE;
PE8.mode_type = OUTPUT_GEN_PURPOSE;
PE8.speed = SPEED_2MHZ;

gpio_init(PE8);

GPIO_TYPE PE9;
PE9.port = PORTE;
PE9.pin = 9;
PE9.mode = OUTPUT_MODE;
PE9.mode_type = OUTPUT_GEN_PURPOSE;
PE9.speed = SPEED_2MHZ;

gpio_init(PE9);


while(1){
        
    gpio_toggle(PORTB,13);
    
    delay_ms(100);
    
    gpio_toggle(PORTB,14);
    
    delay_ms(50);
    
}

}
```

In the HAL_GPIO.c file, I typed the following:

```
#include "HAL_GPIO.h"
#include <stdint.h>
#include "stm32f10x.h"                  // Device header


/*
Every ping in teh high and low control registers has four associated bits
thus the position of every pin is shifted 4 bits. 
This array keeps track of how much each pinNumber has to be shifted to be in the proper bit
*/

static uint32_t PINPOS[16] = {

    (0x00),     //PIN 0
    (0x04),     //PIN 1
    (0x08),     //PIN   2
    (0x0C),     //PIN 3
    (0x10),     //PIN 4
    (0x14),     //PIN 5
    (0x18),     //PIN 6
    (0x1C),     //PIN 7

    (0x00),     //PIN 8
    (0x04),     //PIN 9
    (0x08),     //PIN 10
    (0x0C),     //PIN 11
    (0x10),     //PIN 12
    (0x14),     //PIN 13
    (0x18),     //PIN 14
    (0x1C)      //PIN 15
 };


static void config_pin (GPIO_TypeDef *port, uint32_t pinNumber, uint32_t mode_type){

if(pinNumber >= 8){
    switch(mode_type){
        //Output & Input modes
        case OUTPUT_GEN_PURPOSE | INPUT_ANALOG:
            port -> CRH &= ~((1<<CNF_POB_BIT1) | (1<<CNF_POB_BIT2));
        break;
        
        case OUTPUT_OD | INPUT_FLOATING:
            port -> CRH &= ~( 1<<CNF_POB_BIT2);
            port -> CRH |= (1<<CNF_POB_BIT1);
        break;
        
        case OUTPUT_ALT_FUNCTION | INPUT_PU_PD:
            port -> CRH |= OUTPUT_ALT_FUNCTION << (CNF_POB_BIT1);
        break;
        
        case OUTPUT_ALT_FUNCTION_OD:
            port -> CRH |= OUTPUT_ALT_FUNCTION_OD<<(CNF_POB_BIT1);
        break;
    }
}
else{
    switch(mode_type){
        //Output modes
        case OUTPUT_GEN_PURPOSE | INPUT_ANALOG:
            port -> CRL &= ~((1<<CNF_POB_BIT1) | (1<<CNF_POB_BIT2));
        break;
        
        case OUTPUT_OD | INPUT_FLOATING:
            port -> CRL &= ~( 1<<CNF_POB_BIT2);
            port -> CRL |= (1<<CNF_POB_BIT1);
        break;
        
        case OUTPUT_ALT_FUNCTION | INPUT_PU_PD:
            port -> CRL |= OUTPUT_ALT_FUNCTION << (CNF_POB_BIT1);
        break;
        
        case OUTPUT_ALT_FUNCTION_OD:
            port -> CRL |= OUTPUT_ALT_FUNCTION_OD<<(CNF_POB_BIT1);
        break;
    }
    
}

}


static void config_pin_speed (GPIO_TypeDef *port, uint32_t pinNumber, uint32_t pinSpeed, uint32_t mode){
if (pinNumber >= 8){
    if (mode == INPUT_MODE){
        port -> CRH &= ~(1<<(PINPOS[pinNumber]) | 1<<(PINPOS[pinNumber] + 1));
    }
    else{
        port -> CRH |= (pinSpeed << (PINPOS[pinNumber]));
    }
}
else {
    if (mode == INPUT_MODE){
        port -> CRL &= ~(1<<(PINPOS[pinNumber]) | 1<<(PINPOS[pinNumber]+1)); 
    }
    else {
        port ->CRL |= (pinSpeed << (pinNumber));
    }
}
}



void gpio_write(GPIO_TypeDef *port, uint32_t pinNumber, uint8_t state){

if(state){
    port -> BSRR = (1<<pinNumber);
}
else {
    port -> BSRR = (1<<(pinNumber + 16));
}
}

void gpio_toggle(GPIO_TypeDef *port, uint32_t pinNumber){

port -> ODR ^= (1<<(pinNumber));
}


//initialize 
void gpio_init(GPIO_TYPE gpio_type){

if (gpio_type.port == PORTA){
    GPIO_CLOCK_ENABLE_PORTA;
}
if (gpio_type.port == PORTB){
    GPIO_CLOCK_ENABLE_PORTB;
}
if (gpio_type.port == PORTC){
    GPIO_CLOCK_ENABLE_PORTC;
}
if (gpio_type.port == PORTD){
    GPIO_CLOCK_ENABLE_PORTD;
}
if (gpio_type.port == PORTE){
    GPIO_CLOCK_ENABLE_PORTE;
}

config_pin(gpio_type.port, gpio_type.pin, gpio_type.mode_type);
config_pin_speed(gpio_type.port, gpio_type.pin, gpio_type.speed, gpio_type.mode);
}


//Microsecond delay
void delay_us(uint32_t delay_us){
   volatile unsigned int num;
   volatile unsigned int t;


for (num = 0; num < delay_us; num++)
{
t = 11;
while (t != 0)
{
  t--;
}
}
}
 //Millisecond delay
 void delay_ms(uint16_t delay_ms){
 volatile unsigned int num;
 for (num = 0; num < delay_ms; num++)
 {
  delay_us(1000);
 }
}
```

And, in my HAL_GPIO.h file, I programmed the following:

```
#ifndef _HAL_GPIO
#define _HAL_GPIO

#include "stm32f10x.h"                  // Device header

#define LOW     0
#define HIGH    1

//port names
#define PORTA        GPIOA
#define PORTB        GPIOB
#define PORTC        GPIOC
#define PORTD        GPIOD
#define PORTE        GPIOE
#define PORTF        GPIOF
#define PORTG        GPIOG

//PIN MODE
#define OUTPUT_MODE                                 ((uint32_t) 0x01)
#define INPUT_MODE                                  ((uint32_t) 0x02)

//INPUT MODES TYPE
#define INPUT_ANALOG                            ((uint32_t) 0x00)
#define INPUT_FLOATING                          ((uint32_t) 0x01)   //default at reset
#define INPUT_PU_PD                                 ((uint32_t) 0x02)   //input with pull up 
or pull down

//OUTPUT MODES TYPE
#define OUTPUT_GEN_PURPOSE              ((uint32_t) 0x00)   //general purpose output
#define OUTPUT_OD                       ((uint32_t) 0x01)   //general purpose 
output open-drain
#define OUTPUT_ALT_FUNCTION             ((uint32_t) 0x02)   //alternative function Push-pull
#define OUTPUT_ALT_FUNCTION_OD          ((uint32_t) 0x03)   //alternative function Open-drain

//PIN Speed/slew rate
#define SPEED_2MHZ                                  ((uint32_t) 0x02)
#define SPEED_10MHZ                                 ((uint32_t) 0x01)
#define SPEED_50MHZ                                 ((uint32_t) 0x03)

//clock enabling
#define GPIO_CLOCK_ENABLE_ALT_FUNC      (RCC->APB2ENR |= (1<<0))
#define GPIO_CLOCK_ENABLE_PORTA         (RCC->APB2ENR |= (1<<2))
#define GPIO_CLOCK_ENABLE_PORTB         (RCC->APB2ENR |= (1<<3))
#define GPIO_CLOCK_ENABLE_PORTC         (RCC->APB2ENR |= (1<<4))
#define GPIO_CLOCK_ENABLE_PORTD         (RCC->APB2ENR |= (1<<5))
#define GPIO_CLOCK_ENABLE_PORTE         (RCC->APB2ENR |= (1<<6))
//#define GPIO_CLOCK_ENABLE_PORTF       (RCC->APB2ENR |= (1<<7))
//#define GPIO_CLOCK_ENABLE_PORTG       (RCC->APB2ENR |= (1<<8))

//HIGH BIT POSITION FOR CRH REGISTER CNFYG AND MODE
#define CNF_POB_BIT1                                (PINPOS[pinNumber] + 2)
#define CNF_POB_BIT2                                (PINPOS[pinNumber] + 2)

//Configuration struction
typedef struct{

    GPIO_TypeDef *port;
    
    uint32_t pin;
    uint32_t mode;
    uint32_t mode_type;
    uint32_t pull;
    uint32_t speed;
    uint32_t alt_func;
    
    }GPIO_TYPE;

//Functions
static void config_pin (GPIO_TypeDef *port, uint32_t pinNumber, uint32_t mode_type);

static void config_pin_speed (GPIO_TypeDef *port, uint32_t pinNumber, uint32_t pinSpeed, uint32_t mode);

//gpio pin functions
void gpio_write(GPIO_TypeDef *port, uint32_t pinNumber, uint8_t state);
void gpio_toggle(GPIO_TypeDef *port, uint32_t pinNumber);

//initialize
void gpio_init(GPIO_TYPE gpio_type);

//delay
void delay_us(uint32_t delay_us);
void delay_ms(uint16_t delay_ms);


#endif
```

I hope someone could help me, thank you very much!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please simplify the problem and provide more debugging info: Remove any loops and delays in the code and just set the GPIOs to the desired level for a single LED. Disconnect the circuit from the MCU and measure whether the GPIOs behave as expected. Test the LED circuit separately without MCU. Then come back with more specific questions.

Comment: After having looked at your question again, I think you are trying too much at once. You have soldered a non-trivial LED circuit. Have you tested it? You have written your own HAL code for STM32. Have you tested it (in particular the delay code)? The matrix requires a special driving model that can control at most a single row or column of LEDs at once. Do you fully understand it? (The way you initialize the GPIOs indicates otherwise.) Split your solution, test each part individually and the put it together one by one.

Comment: I have tested all the LED on the board, and the delay code only for the LED on the test board of stm32f103vet6. They all worked. But when I test the LED matrix, I found that even if I test only one LED on the board with similar codes, it will not be lightened.

Comment: After several other kinds of test, I found you are right that I am trying too much. And I am going to buy some mosfets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to light up many LEDs at the time without exceeding maximum output current spec of one port or entire IC. If you light up 15 LEDs with GPIOs, you will burn MCU even if you didn't exceed current spec on each individual pin. **There is a total current limitation for the package and for each individual port, and this limitation is less than the sum of all max currents per pin times number of pins**. Make sure you don't exceed any of those specs at any point of operation. Maybe you would want to find an LED driver IC which will take commands from MCU?

Also, I suggest you start with blinking a single LED. After all, if you can light up one, you can light up as many as you want. There is more than enough tutorials about how to do it with HAL or without HAL using only low level stuff, down to manual register manipulation, if you are that kind of a person. It's one of the first examples in any tutorial anyway.

If you're using CubeIDE, you can auto-generate all the setup of the pins. HAL time overhead will probably be totally negligible in your application.

Try

```
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_9); //Toggle the state of pin PC9
```

This syntax where you turn the stuff on. Since you have HAL library connected anyway, might as well use its functions, right?